# No WiFi network detected except Hotspots on Dell Inspiron with Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, dell, iwlwifi

My laptop, which is a Dell Inspiron 4210 and have Ubuntu 18.04.2 running,  can't detect wifi networks except hotspots. Ethernet is working fine. It can connect to the hotspots. I can see that there is an inbuilt card "Intel Corporation Wireless 3160". WiFi is not hard blocked. Secureboot is disabled. I can't seem to find a way for it to detect wifi networks. Please help.

[Here are the outputs of some commands which might assist in resolving this issue](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MntBcdXhQ3/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still have and issue or not. I seen your message as I was experiencing the same issue with a dell inspiron 15 5558 laptop using the same wifi adapter (3160) and lost connectivity at the same time as yourself. I'm using Antergos, Arch based distro. Just wanted you to know that removing expressvpn (not sure if you use that or not) resolved the issue. The interesting thing in my case was that when I reinstalled expressvpn again, reenabled and started it in systemd the wifi still worked. I rebooted and all still came back up. This is what worked for me. It may or may not be relevant to yourself. Even if you don't have expressvpn installed you may wish to look at what 3rd party apps you have and look for potential culprits. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't have expressvpn. I will definitely look for culprits in the third party apps and let you know if it works.